# Is there a way to have a multilevel mediation analysis with two independent variables?

Tags: r, multi-level

I got two Level 2 independent variables, one level 1 mediators and one level 1 Dependent variables.  Not an expert in R and I tried to locate the code online.  So far, the codes or tutorials are meant for one level 2 independent variable. I asked ChatGPT and this is the answer.  From my limited knowledge, that does not sounds right about it.  It would be great if you can point me to the right direction.

model <- lmer(dependent_var ~ independent_var1 + independent_var2 + (1 | group), data = your_data)